# putc() writes wrong data

Tags: c, char

```
int writeFile(FILE * handle, char * data, int len)
{
    fseek(handle, 0, SEEK_SET);
    for(int i=0; i <= len; i++)
        putc(data[i], handle);
}
```

When I call this function, it works fine, but if there is a 0x1A character on `char * data` it will write countless 0xFF. Why is that?

Comment: Why not `fwrite(data, 1, len, handle)`?

Comment: How countless are the countless 0xFF?  Are you sure that the count isn't simply the number of characters after the 0x1A (control-Z) character in the string you're writing, give or take the off-by-one error in your code?

Comment: C or C++? Pick one? This is not code you should use in C++. And if you can't count, then perhaps programming is not for you.

Answer (score 6):

Hex 0x1A is also known as Control-Z.

On Windows (well, DOS originated it), text files indicate EOF by embedding a control-Z in the file.

If you want to write binary data, make sure the output file is opened as a binary file.  If you open it as a text file, only output text (which means very limited control characters; probably just tabs and newlines, with the system taking care of CRLF <--> LF mapping).

Comment: Wow great! It's exactly what you said. I added a 'b' on mode argument of fopen function, and it worked. thanks

Comment: CPM originated it because CPM didn't store the size of the file in bytes but in the number of disk blocks. The end of the valid part of the file in the last block was marqued with 0x1A.

Comment: @AProgrammer: Thanks - somehow, that doesn't surprise me, but I'd forgotten about CP/M.

Answer (score 2):

You're writing `len+1` characters instead of `len` characters.

Change:

```
for(int i=0; i <= len; i++)
```

to:

```
for(int i=0; i < len; i++)
```

(Note that this bug was already mentioned in comments to your previous question - be sure to read *all* your answers and comments carefully.)

Comment: Dit it. The problem persists. I'm sure this is happening due to the 0x1A char, I still dont know why. If i remove the 0x1a char from data, it works fine

Comment: @user1091856: Remove the 0x1A character, then. It shouldn't be there.